Moving pauli product rotations past measurements
I'm trying to understand how the clifford + T compiler works in "A Game of Surface codes".

How do I move a pauli product rotation block past a pauli product measurement block? More specifically, how do I get from a) to b).
a) 
b) 
Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be two tensor products of Paulis. Imagine you have a gate sequence
$$
e^{i\theta\tau}\sqrt{\sigma},
$$
then you can always rewrite this as
$$
e^{i\theta\tau}=\sqrt{\sigma}e^{i\theta\sqrt{\sigma}^\dagger\tau\sqrt{\sigma}}\sqrt{\sigma}^\dagger
$$
such that
$$
e^{i\theta\tau}\sqrt{\sigma}=\sqrt{\sigma}e^{i\theta\sqrt{\sigma}^\dagger\tau\sqrt{\sigma}}.
$$
In other words, we have moved the $\sqrt{\sigma}$ the other term, but the other term has updated from $\tau$ to $\sqrt{\sigma}^\dagger\tau\sqrt{\sigma}$. If $\tau$ and $\sigma$ commute, this just leaves $\tau$. But if they anti-commute, you get $\tau\sigma$ (up to an $i$ phase that I'm not being very careful about.
This manipulation doesn't care if it's a unitary that $\tau$ is doing, or a measurement, where $\theta$ might as well be $\pi/2$.

That makes sense. Thank you so much!
